# TLS/SSL encryption in MQTT Mosquitto is not working

Tags: encryption, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using Mosquitto MQTT to send some monitoring measurements from a remote Raspberry Pi to my local Raspberry Pi. Everything works when the traffic is unencrypted and running over port 8001. I am using a password for authentication, however as it is sent in plain text it does not give much security. Therefore, I would like to use TLS/SSL encryption, which I unfortunately cannot set up.

I am not good with networking, but I try to explain everything as detailed as possible.

- `sudo ufw allow 8883`
- Port forwarding in my router from LAN -> WAN with 80 -> 80, 443 -> 443, 8883 -> 8883
- `sudo ufw allow 80` # I guess that is only necessary to get the certificate.
- `sudo ufw allow 443` # I don't know if that is necessary.
- I created Let's Encrypt certificates with `sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d domain.com` # domain.com just is a place holder
- `sudo systemctl status mosquitto.service`is running.

/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.config

```
persistence false
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

listener 1883 192.168.0.235

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
# tls_version tlsv1.2

allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf is empty.

My problem is that the publishing and subscription is not working. On the Raspberry Pi with the broker I run `mosquitto_sub -h domain.com -t test --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ -d -p 8883`. I am not sure her if `--capath`has to be `/etc/ssl/certs/`or the directory from letsencrypt `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/`.

On the publishing site: Do I have to copy any of the certificates (cert.pem, fullchain.pem or privkey.pem) to the publishing Raspberry Pi? Because I think I am missing something, because `mosquitto_pub -h domain.com -t test -m "Hello World!" -d -p 8883` does not work.

So I think I have all pieces available, but I did not put them correctly together. Any help or feedback is highly appreciated and I am happy to help with addtional information or logs. In the next step I would like to automatize it with paho-mqtt in Python.

Regards.

Comment: Is the publishing Pi on the same network as your broker? If so does your router support Hairpin NAT?

Comment: Also edit the question to show the error messages you get from the clients and the mosquitto logs from when you try and connect.

Answer (score 1):

On your `mosquitto.conf`, `certfile` should point to `fullchain.pem` and `cafile` should point to `/etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem`.

When you connect to the broker, either using `mosquitto_pub` or `mosquitto_sub`, you need to pass the root certificate so the client can verify the broker's certificate. So in both cases you should pass `--cafile /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem` (do not use `--capath` as it won't work with .pem files)

In addition, you have `allow_anonymous false`, which means that the broker expects that you pass username and password when connecting. I suggest to change it to `true` first so you can focus on get the tls connection working.

Can you try this and share wheter it worked?